# How to enforce 1 Bean instance and avoid NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm implementing a websocket service where incoming messages are passed to controllers and the controllers can then broadcast response messages to another websocket session(s).

When they broadcast the message back, there is either 1 of 2 issues. Either `MySocketHandler` is a different instance than the one that handled `afterConnectionEstablished` (using Autowired annotation on `MySocketHandler` in `MessageRouter` seems to create a new instance) or I get `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException` (if I use ApplicationContext to specifically get the bean by class type).

An instance of my application should only have 1 `MySocketHandler`, so I annotated `MySocketHandler` with `@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)`.

I suspect this has something to do with asynchronous event publishing and listening. I've refactored this code a few times to try to implement this the "Spring" way but there's some fundamental error each time.

I want to know how I can enforce the Spring container to create and reuse only 1 instance of MySocketHandler.

Here is my a minimalized version of `MySocketHandler.java` to exemplify the problem:

```
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class MySocketHandler extends BinaryWebSocketHandler {

    @Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext
    @Autowired private MessageRouter messageRouter;

    private final HashMap<String, WebSocketSession> sessions = new HashMap<>();

    @EventListener
    public void onOutgoingBinaryMessageEvent(OutgoingBinaryMessageEvent event) {
        // ERROR: NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException
    applicationContext.getBean(MySocketHandler.class).broadcast(event.getBytes(), event.getConnectionIds());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterConnectionEstablished(WebSocketSession session) {
        sessions.put(session.getId(), session);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleBinaryMessage(WebSocketSession session, BinaryMessage message) {
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(new IncomingBinaryMessageEvent(
                this,
                message.getPayload().array(),
                session.getId()));
    }

    private void broadcast(byte[] bytes, Set<String> playerIds) {
        BinaryMessage binaryMessage = new BinaryMessage(bytes);
    // this.sessions is null because its a different instance of MySocketHandler than the one that actually managing the connections
        for (WebSocketSession session : sessions.values()) {
            try {
                webSocketSession.sendMessage(binaryMessage);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }            
        }
    }
}
```

And an example of the `MessageRouter.java`:

```
@Component
public class MessageRouter {
    @Autowired private ApplicationEventPublisher eventPublisher;

    public void send(Message message) {
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(message);
    }

    @EventListener
    private void routeMessageToController(SomeMessageEvent any, String connectionId) {
        .....
        // Parse message and route it to a controller class.
        .....
        }
    }
}
```

Application entry point:

```
public class MyApplication implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(getSocketHandler(), "/").setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
    }

    @Bean
    public MySocketHandler getSocketHandler() {
        return new MySocketHandler();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> An instance of my application should only have 1 MySocketHandler, so I
> annotated MySocketHandler with
> @Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON).

First of all , singleton is applied in the bean level but not the type level. It can't ensure your application will only has the single bean of a particular type. You can still define multiple singleton bean for the same type.

In most general cases , a bean can be defined by the following ways:

- Annotating the class with `@Component` (or its specialisation version such as `@Repository` , `@Service` , `@Controller` , `@Configuration` etc.)
- Using `@Bean` method in the `@Configuration` class

Now you are doing :

```java
@Component
@Scope(ConfigurableBeanFactory.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
public class MySocketHandler extends BinaryWebSocketHandler 

}
```

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication implements WebSocketConfigurer {

     @Bean
     public MySocketHandler getSocketHandler() {
            return new MySocketHandler();
     }
}
```

<sup>*Note: `@SpringBootApplication` is a composed annotation which contain `@Configuration`*</sup>

which means you are now defining two `MySocketHandler` beans . One with the name `mySocketHandler` (defined via `@Component`) and the other has the name `getSocketHandler` (defined via `@Bean`)

So to ensure there is only one `MySocketHandler` bean , either remove `@Component` from `MySocketHandler` or remove this `@Bean` method.